# How do i get a sword or any tools in Minecraft java edition with a specific amount of durablity

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there a way to get a sword that is used and has only half of its durability left, or has a specific amount of durability left? e.g.: i want a netherite sword with 1024 durability remaining, but still has the same amount of maximum durability.

Comment: Welcome to [Arqade](/tour)! Please see our [guide on asking Minecraft commands questions](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far.” Then, [edit] your post and add the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is. Using this command.

> /give @p minecraft:netherite_sword{Damage: 1007}

The number after "Damage:" is the amount of durability subtracted from the total durability of the item.